# Hook into and log "everything" in the windows message queue

Tags: python, windows, message-queue

Has anyone got a working code example of how to connect to the windows message queue(post/sendMessage) and log all messages there? Preferably in Python.
I'm interrested in this to easier be able to create test-scripts that emulates user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done with [SetWindowsHookEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx).

In Python you probably must use 3rd party libraries, like [Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).
[PyCWnd.HookMessage](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyCWnd__HookMessage_meth.html) and [PyCWnd.HookAllKeyStrokes](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyCWnd__HookAllKeyStrokes_meth.html) might be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a package that wraps the SetWindowsHookEx function, called [pyHook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page).  I've used it before to write a primitive key-logger (as an experiment in monitoring myself to assist with reporting work hours) and it worked fine for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640(VS.85).aspx) to catch most system windowing activity. The advantage from traditional hooks is that you can do it from your process, that is, you don't need to write a hooking DLL. Also, when the thread that called SetWinEventHook finishes, Windows releases the handler automatically. Having out of context hooking prevents you from crashing other applications, as a minimal error on an injected DLL will possibly do.